# Definite integral of arbitrary-base exponent is undefined

Tags: integration

The integral of an arbitrary-base exponent can be given as $$\int_0^x a^{x_0} d{x_0} = \frac{a^x - 1}{\ln(a)}$$
by $a^{x_0} = e^{x_0 \ln a}$.

At $a = 1$ when $f(x) = a^x = 1$, the definite integral shown above should clearly be $F(x) = x$, but is instead undefined by $\frac{a^x-1}{\ln(a)}$.

How can the integral be evaluated to accurately represent the behavior of $f(x)$? I have tried rearranging terms and applying various properties of logarithms/exponents but have had no success.

I am more interested in closed form solutions as something like a Taylor approximation is trivial but not particularly useful when $x$ is large.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. What is $f(x)$ in this  case? It seems like you have evaluated the integral (although you have split it into two different cases). What are you trying to approximate?

Comment: $f(x)$ was just used to refer to $a^x$ and its integral, $F(x)$. The integral has not been split into cases, but I am asking about how to fix its being incorrect when $a=1$. And I am not trying to approximate anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hospital for
$$ \frac{a^x - 1}{\log(a)}\to \frac 0 0 \quad \text{when} \quad a\to1$$
$$ \frac{[a^x - 1]'}{[\log(a)]'}=\frac{x a^{x-1} }{\frac{1}{a} }=a^x x \quad \to \quad x$$

**Edit**

By Taylor,
$$ \frac{a^x - 1}{\log(a)}=x+\frac{1}{2} (a-1) x^2+O\left((a-1)^2\right)$$ By continuity, the function is defined at $a=1$.

Comment: Using a limit here is more of a workaround as it does not address the incorrect behavior of the evaluated integral. It *should* be defined even when $a = 1$.

Comment: @wwilliamcook. Have a look at my edit

Comment: The original function contains a removable discontinuity at $a = 1$ which the Taylor series removes, but that does not mean the original function is defined at $a = 1$. Is there no way to modify/rearrange the original function to make it fully defined $\forall a > 0$?